# Please advise me why I can't get date("I") in php to work

Tags: php, date

I can't get this to work!

We changed to daylight savings time today - more than eight hours ago. And yet the date("I") function is still returning "0" not "1". If I use this code:

```
<?php
echo(date("I"));
?>
```

it returns 0

It's driving me up the wall - any thoughts please?

Comment: I get 1. What time zone are you in. Not all parts of the world change to summertime at the same time. And is the server in your country?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I've sorted it now - see below.  I had thought of that - I'm in the UK - and so I waited for 8 hours, which I figured was well after most of the world had changed to DST!  Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your timezone correctly:

```
echo date_default_timezone_get(); // UTC
echo date('I'); // 0

// configure timezone correctly
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/Amsterdam');
echo date('I'); // 1
```

You can also configure it in the php.ini file directly or by calling `date_default_timezone_set()`.

[Read more about date_default_timezone_get() in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php)

---

However, I would encourage you to use DateTime instead, since configuring the timezone globally can have unintended side-effects.

```
$dt = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam'));
echo $dt->format("I"); // 1
```

Comment: OK - that last one seems to work.  I was actually trying to print out a time that was half an hour before sunset, and I've incorporated your code into the following statement

echo"<b>".(date_sunset(time(),SUNFUNCS_RET_STRING,52.639561,-0.640314,90.6,($dt->format("I"))-0.5))."</b>";

As I'm in the UK, I've used:

$dt = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));

Although I'm not convinced this is entirely correct as the UK is one hour ahead of most of Europe.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "most of Europe" but you are **behind** central Europe. https://3v4l.org/Lm2gv